# Fullscreen Pageflip Layout to slideright full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm a follower of Codrops tutorials by Tympanus.

I am trying to make the flip page to slide page of the existing code from following reference link http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/11/fullscreen-pageflip-layout/

Actually i want to know whether flip page can be converted to slide page..
kindly help me to convert the flip page to slide page may be from right to left or left to right..

Thanks and Regards
Manoj

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i want convert the book flip to slide as an image

Answer (score 0):

This template using BookBlock JS. You can see it with link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/03/bookblock-a-content-flip-plugin/